# Is Visual C++ a good Choice to start visual programming?

Tags: delphi, visual-c++

My friends have to build a program whitch contain some forms ...they have to choose between VC++ and Delphi but many people said that VC++ is not a good place to build Winforms applications so is this true ? 
My friend are beginners and they only Know few things in C++ and Delphi so what is the best choice ?

Edit : this is a university program and c# and other languages aren't allowed.

Comment: And C# isn't an option at all?

Comment: why not C#? it is much more simpler to build UI applications using it

Comment: @Rowland: Unfortunately this is a university program and c# isn't allowed.

Comment: @fadi Yet they allow Delphi. That's "odd"...

Comment: @Rowland Shaw - maybe a legacy requirement from a school that has Borland software and offered the options of using Delphi or C++ Builder.  Unless somebody has a bee in their bonnet about garbage collectors, the restrictions are probably bureaucratic in nature - some decision that they don't have in-house skills with Java or .Net, don't have any licences for Visual Studio or something similar.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells probably the case, although he did talk of Visual C++; I suspect it's an internal skills thing (how can they mark the quality of the code, if they don't understand it); Whilst not familiar with the exact terms, there is the free-to-use express editions for C#, etc, which *might* solve the cost issue...

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells it is because they are in the first year and c# is allowed in the third year...the cost is not an issue in our country because everyone can buy the latest edition from VS (any type of VS) with 1$ or less! the onions is more expensive than any program here!

Comment: @Naveen - Building forms in Delphi is no harder than in C#. The Delphi Visual Conrtol Library (VCL) predates WinForms by 5 years.

Comment: @Fabricio Araujo : in Syria http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syria

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend that you use [Delphi](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi), is very easy to learn and you can do [amazing things](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Good_Quality_Applications_Built_With_Delphi) in a small time, is incredibly productive, has a very well designed Visual library ([VCL](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Visual_Component_Library)) and has a very fast compiler wich produces standalone executables (without dependences).

There are many known applications developed in Delphi like [Skype (Windows Client)](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/home), [Toad](http://toadfororacle.com/index.jspa), [Fl Studio](http://flstudio.image-line.com/). also has a very active community, there are also [thousands of third-party](http://www.torry.net/) components that you can use in your applications, once you start using delphi never coming back.

about the subject of the work is true that demand is less than those provided for C# or C++, but if you become a good Delphi programmer never have trouble finding a job.

Comment: I completely agree. I had to take a few C++ and Visual C++ courses in college and while it was good to learn, I wish I would've had the opportunity to formally take a Delphi course in college.

Comment: And if C++ is an option, and thats what  you know, C++ Builder is great as well.

Comment: just to add my two cents... Skype uses C++ with Qt4 for its Linux client. @Mick I'd highly recommend that you'd look into Qt - its worth spending some time researching it.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few possible strategies, depending on your friend's interest and career options.

- Case 1: Your firends have no interest in computer science, they just need to get this assignment over with: Choose Delphi, it's easier to swallow.
- Case 2: They want to learn something they might use in the future, but no serious programmer prospect: Do it with Delphi! While Delphi is *very* expensive, it's closer to C#, and the casual future programming is likely going to be done using C#
- Case 3: Serious programmer prospects: Do it with C++, even if you really like Delphi. C++ is very unlikely going to be "the future" of commercial software development but any self-respecting programmer should learn it. Even better, do it with both C++ and Delphi.

Now if this were about "what tool should I buy for MY software startup" that's easy. If you have a choice go with Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi is a nice language to learn programming, as the syntax is clear and you can achieve first results very fast. However, Delphi's future seems unclear, so if you want to learn a language with the hope of using it in your career, better go for something else. If you can't use neither Java nor c#, I'd vote for C++ with QT.

Comment: C++ is an open standard and there are compilers and tools from different companies as well as a complete open source chain. So you can be quite confident, that there will be good support for C++ in the future. Delphi is the child of only one company (Borland, than Codegear, now Embarcadero) and therefore much more vulnerable.

Comment: I must admit I'm very biased towards commercial software development (the kind that pays the bills). Open source is irrelevant in this domain, and source-level compatibility between vendors is not exactly there, because there's more to C++ then just the language: you need the libraries. No matter what choice you make, you're going to choose one vendor and hope it lives long enough.

Comment: I can just tell you, that open source tools (gcc, cmake, mercurial, valgrind to name a few) help pay my bills and those of my co-workers just fine.

Comment: I humbly consider my self novice as a developer, so please correct me if I am wrong. I fully support @fschmitt, and would like to add that Qt is open-source too and available for commercial software development (thanks to LGPL). Anyways this discussion here is useless as the question is asked by students, so they are concerned less about commercial production and perhaps would be happier with open-source stuff.

Answer (score 2):

C# is a good choice for Winforms applications.

Delphi might be easier (and therefore better for beginners) than VC++, but it's less commonly used commercially (so fewer jobs using it). It's often chosen by self-employed developers.

Answer (score 2):

There is the option of using C++ with Visual Studio (the editor is great and comfortable, but I don't know Delphi) with the [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) library.

Qt is great and easy to get started with. The API is so clean that you could eat on it.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to choose between Delphi and C++, I'd certainly go for Delphi because you plan to build an WinForms UI

Now if you mention C++, I guess you envisage visual studio (express edition?) and in that case I'd go for C#

The father of C# is also the father of Delphi, you'll find many similarities between the 2 languages

Comment: buddy, you should seriously look into Qt, it's open-source, it's totally free and it's amazingly clean and easy to use. plus, you get it all in one package - the compiler, the IDE, the library and the instant offline help. what else can a developer look for. and if that's not enough - it is cross-platform (Windows, Mac and Linux) - if someone cares.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for VC++ mainly because it's more mainstream. Delphi is easy/nice has a little bit awkward syntax and are not as popular (Can be difficult to find IDE/books/resources).

Delphi: easy and productive, peaked among programmer popularity long time ago
VC++: steep learning curve, more mainstream

But in the end it really doesn't matter, what's important is that you code and have fun. Whichever you choose you will learn tons that will benefit you in your future career. Good luck!

Comment: Delphi has awkward syntax??? Never heard that one before. I guess it doesn't have the elegance of Perl nor the nice layout of Python...

Comment: Also ask why there's no contest to write obfuscated code in Delphi ;)

Comment: @Idsandon - I'm actually surprised that anyone saw a need to for an obfuscated C contest - isn't all C obfuscated? (OK not as bad as Perl)

Answer (score 1):

Why not C++ Builder? Delphi is Pascal.

Comment: “Delphi is Pascal” – (1) So what? (2) Wine is grape seeds. Well actually, no: one developed from the other.

Comment: Always funny how defensive Delphi users get :). Clearly there was already a preference for C++ (or else I do not understand why VC++ is included), so I was merely making sure OP was aware of a Delphi-like C++ alternative.

Comment: I have never in my life used either Delphi or Pascal. But I don’t understand what value that statement holds.

Comment: Ah, you may not be aware then that Delphi and C++ Builders are the same, the only difference being Delphi uses Pascal and C++ Builder, like VC++, use C++.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your answer. Thanks for the explanation.